# VSTO my add in is prevent other Outlook items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ribbonx

I am adding a plugin in Outlook (2013 and up). Click on My Add-on Open a specific parameters window, this window becomes modal and prevents access to other Outlook items.
Only if I confirm or cancel this parameters can I access other items.
I probably need to add some functionality in Click_event to the ribbon in my-add-in.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e){
//e.Control.Tag is "RibbonId=Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer"
}
```

Any idea how can I prevent this behavior? What I need add to my click_event ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to show a non-modal window by using the [Form.Show(IWin32Window)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method instead of [Form.ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: If i use Form.Show() - I am not accept returned value from opened dialog (Save/Cancel). Form.Show() - opens a window and returns without waiting for the newly opened window to close.

Comment: You need to specify the parent window handle for the `Show` method like mentioned in my post.